# Convert hours-based timestamps to Python class (like datetime) for time delta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Ok, so I have a log with timestamps like these:

```
120H08M48.862S
120H08M49.062S
```

So, the hours can be larger than 24 - however, minutes wrap at 60 as usual, seconds do as well too - and seconds have a millisecond fractional part as well.

Is it possible to convert these kinds of timestamps to datetime (or some other Python class) - such that I could calculate delta between them easily (say "120H08M49.062S"-"20H08M49.010S" should give 100 hours and 50 milliseconds)?

I have tried this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("120H08M48.862S", '%HH%MM%SS')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '120H08M48.862S' does not match format '%HH%MM%SS'
```

... but it doesn't work.

Comment: `pandas.to_timedelta` can readily parse this, and there are other parsers like e.g. [pytimeparse](https://pypi.org/project/pytimeparse/)

Comment: agreed with @MrFuppes I just tested your sample with `pd.to_timedelta` and it gives `5 days 8 mins and 48/49 seconds` as the output.

Comment: Thanks all - `pd.to_timedelta('120H08M48.862S')` does seem to work fine!

Comment: @sdbbs why don't you add pandas as a tag and answer the question?